# Yii2 compare date in model with function

Tags: validation, date, model, compare, yii2

I have model with below rules

```
public function rules()
{
  return [    
   ['student_dob', 
        function ($attr) {
            $curr_date = date('d-m-Y');
            if(empty($this->student_adm_date)) {
                //$this->addError('student_dob',"Select Admission date first"); 
                return true;
            }
            else {
              $dob = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->$attr));
              $adm = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->student_adm_date));
              $diff = $adm-$dob;
               if($diff <= 14)  {
            
                $this->addError('student_dob', "Birth date must be less than Admission date."); 
                return false;   
    
               }

               else
                return true;
            }
            
            },
        ]
    ];
}
```

This rule works good but error message don't appear on view page and my form view is below

```
<?php   $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{label}\n{beginWrapper}\n{input}\n{error}\n{endWrapper}",
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'label' => 'col-sm-4',
            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-4',
            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-8',
            'error' => '',
            'hint' => '',
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
<div class="row-left">
            <?= $form->field($info, 'student_dob', ['template' => "{label} {input} <span class='status'>&nbsp;</span> {error}"])->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),
                    [
            'model'=>$info, 
            'attribute'=>'student_dob',
            'value'=>'',
                        'clientOptions' =>[
                        'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                        'changeMonth'=> true,
                        'changeYear'=> true,
                        'autoSize'=>true,
                        'showOn'=> "button",
            'yearRange'=>'1900:'.(date('Y')+1),
                        'buttonImage'=> Yii::$app->homeUrl."images/calendar.png",
                        'htmlOptions'=>[
                        'style'=>'width:250px;',
                          'class'=>'form-control',
                         ]]]); ?> 
            
        </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I want to compare `student_dob` and `student_adm_date` with `student_dob < student_adm_date` rule validation, also error appear on form view page.

---

#### Solution

Just remove `horizontalCssClasses` and change `template` value like,

```
<?php   $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'layout' => 'horizontal',
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{error}",
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting one sting from another, I am not sure that works

```
$diff = $adm - $dob;
```

Try

```
if(strtotime($this->$attr) <= strtotime($this->student_adm_date))
```

Or change it to calcualte 14 days... altough not sure what you can register somebody 14 days after their birth.
You can calculate

```
if(strtotime($this->$attr) - strtotime($this->student_adm_date) > 60 * 60 * 24 * 14)
```

One more thing, in the validation functions you do not need `return false;`   or `return true;` Try removing these, I personally do not know if they do anything.

Comment: validation is already working but error message is doesn't appear on form field...